# Simulating routing for Django Rest Framework testing?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm testing my Django Rest Framework app ViewSet, and I'm running into routing issues. I don't want to specify the action the ViewSet must take as in: `view = MyViewSet.as_view("get": "retrieve")`.

I'd like to simulate the routing that would actually take place. I get a `TypeError` dictating that I must specify the actions on a ViewSet every time I try to call `as_view` with no arguments. Advice? What is the idiomatically correct way to test such code?